# How to automatically add Bean Validation when partially updating PATCH Spring Boot MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bean-validation

As we all know, there is a big problem with a partial update of the entity. Since the automatic conversion from json strings to the entity, all fields that have not been transferred will be marked null. And as a result, the fields that we did not want to reset will be reset.

I will show the classical scheme:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EmployeeController.PATH)
public class EmployeeController {

    public final static String PATH = "/employees";

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public Employee update(@RequestBody Employee employee, @PathVariable Long id) {
        return service.update(id, employee);
    }
}

@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Employee update(Long id, Employee entity) {
        Optional<T> optionalEntityFromDB = repository.findById(id);
        return optionalEntityFromDB
                .map(e -> saveAndReturnSavedEntity(entity, e))
                .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }

    private T saveAndReturnSavedEntity(Employee entity, Employee entityFromDB) {
        entity.setId(entityFromDB.getId());
        return repository.save(entity);
    }
}

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

and as I have already said that in the current implementation we will not be able to perform a partial update in any way. That is, it is impossible to send an update of only one field in a json line; all fields will be updated, and in null (excepted passed).

The solution to this problem is that you need to perform the conversion from string json to the entity in manual. That is, do not use all the magic from Spring Boot (which is very sad).

I will also give an example of how this can be implemented using merge at the json level:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EmployeeRawJsonController.PATH)
public class EmployeeRawJsonController {

    public final static String PATH = "/raw-json-employees";

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRawJsonService service;

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public Employee update(@RequestBody String json, @PathVariable Long id) {
        return service.update(id, json);
    }
}

@Service
public class EmployeeRawJsonService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public Employee update(Long id, String json) {
        Optional<Employee> optionalEmployee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
        return optionalEmployee
                .map(e -> getUpdatedFromJson(e, json))
                .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }

    private Employee getUpdatedFromJson(Employee employee, String json) {
        Long id = employee.getId();

        updateFromJson(employee, json);

        employee.setId(id);
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    private void updateFromJson(Employee employee, String json) {
        try {
            new ObjectMapper().readerForUpdating(employee).readValue(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot update from json", e);
        }
    }
}

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

With this solution, we eliminate the problem associated with the partial update.

But here another problem arises, that we are losing the automatic addition of validation of beans.

That is, in the first case, validation is enough to add one annotation @Valid:

```
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
public Employee update(@RequestBody @Valid Employee employee, @PathVariable Long id) {
    return service.update(id, employee);
}
```

But we can't do the same when we perform manual deserialization.

My question is, is there any way to enable automatic validation for the second case?
Or maybe there are other solutions that allow you to use Spring Boot magic for Bean Validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not the normal validation , which can achieved through manual validator call.Let’s now go the manual route and set things up programmatically:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(object);
for (ConstraintViolation<User> violation : violations) {
log.error(violation.getMessage()); 
}
```

To validate a bean, we must first have a Validator object, which is constructed using a ValidatorFactory.

Normal validations on Spring Controllers specified with @Valid annotations are triggered automatically during the DataBinding phase when a request is served.All validators registered with the DataBinder will be executed at that stage. We can't do that for your case, so you can manually trigger the validation like above.